# Postgres not accepting commands and Vacuum failed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

First of all, yes, its an old version of Postgres (8.4), but upgrading is not an option at present.

On a large production database with many tables and rows, the database went down with the following error:

```
dbname user 2017-09-13 13:30:01.570 UTC  ERROR:  database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database "dbname"
dbname user 2017-09-13 13:30:01.570 UTC  HINT:  Stop the postmaster and use a standalone backend to vacuum database "dbname".
        You might also need to commit or roll back old prepared transactions.
```

We attempted to Vacuum the database (in single user mode), however this was not very successful (ran for 12 hours before failing):

```
backend> vacuum;
  2017-09-15 05:40:10.439 UTC  ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 1453898
  2017-09-15 05:40:10.439 UTC  STATEMENT:  vacuum;
backend>
```

After a restart the database was still not accepting commands. We tried a reindex, but that failed due to the original issue.

I attempted to locate OID 1453898 using:

```
SELECT 1453898::regclass;
```

But no results returned.

What else can be done to clean up and resolve this issue?

Comment: with XID exceeded maximum and not existing relations I would start thinking on dumping and restoring the data (preferably to some adequate version)

Comment: I might go down that route, although upgrading version is not possible due to some internal postgres changes which make the application not directly compatible with newer versions.